# Select value from the dropdown in which the data are taken from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I need to post the value from the `drop down`, in which the dropdown contains items which are retrieved from the database. To display the item of the table I use `echo` in the option. But then, I need to get that value of item selected to be updated in the database. As be seen below, I've tried the code which (surely) will not work. How is it possible to get the the value of selected item?
Your suggestion will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

```
<select name="user" class="form-control" id="user">
<?php while ($hasil = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){ ?>    
<option name="user_name"><?php echo $hasil['user_name'] ?></option>
<option name="user_name" value="<?php echo $hasil['user_name'] ?>" hidden></option><?php }?>    
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="user" class="form-control" id="user">
<?php while ($hasil = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){ ?>    
<option><?php echo $hasil['user_name'] ?></option>   
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

This code solves your problem, Check at your side and let me know in case of any issue.
We need to give name only once in select tag and no need to add a extra option only for value.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I get the value of the items selcted and post it in the database?

Comment: You have given a php script name in action, In that file you need to get this variable value by $_GET or $_POST (According to your need)
if you are using post method in form then You may use $_POST['user']
and if you are using get method in form then you may use $_GET['uesr']
After that you need to execute a query for inserting value in database

Answer (score 0):

You must fill your dropdown from base table after that you must check value or id from second table that stored in database. If id or value is equal you must set selected='selected' in your option element

Answer (score 0):

- Hope it is help you to resolve you problem

" >
" >
" >

*

Comment: <option value="<?php echo $hasil['user_name'] ?>" <?php echo ($hasil['user_name'] == $comparevalue) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $hasil['user_name']; ?></option>
<option value="<?php echo $hasil['user_name'] ?>" <?php echo ($hasil['user_name'] == $comparevalue) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $hasil['user_name']; ?></option><option value="<?php echo $hasil['user_name'] ?>" <?php echo ($hasil['user_name'] == $comparevalue) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $hasil['user_name']; ?</option>